# Equation of force (Goldstein equation) $f=-\frac{k}{r^2}$

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

[image]
[image]

$$f'=-\frac{\partial V'}{\partial r}=f(r)+\frac{l^2}{mr^3}$$
which agrees with Eq. (3.22). The energy conservation theorem (3.15) can thus also be written as
$$E=V'+\frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2  \tag{3.15'}$$
As an illustration of this method of examining the motion, consider a plot of $V'$ against $r$ for the specific case of an attractice inverse-square law of force:
$$f=-\frac{k}{r^2}$$ (For positive k, the minus sign ensures that the force is toward the center of force.) The potential energy for this force is $$V=-\frac{k}{r}$$

I was trying to illustrate a plot of V' against r. See what I found in Desmos:

[image]

Parabola!!! Now, how they found $f=-\frac{k}{r^2}$? I know that $k$ is constant. But, nothing is coming to my head after illustrating that plot.

Comment: You seem to be using $f$ to denote two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The question boils down to: how are potential energy $V$ and force $f$ related?

**Answer**: potential energy $V$ at $r$ is the work we need to do when we want to move the particle from $r$ to infinity. Since work is force times distance we have
$$
V(r)=\int_r^\infty f(x)\,dx=-\int_r^\infty\frac{k}{x^2}\,dx=-\frac{k}{r}\,.
$$